# Should an applicant admit to having paranoid schizophrenia?

Tags: hiring

The person in question is a hobbyist programmer since their childhood and wants to make a transition to junior developer.  S/he has never worked before.

A few facts about the person:

- The person is passionate about programming, and quite knowledgeable as well.
- S/he knows his/her data structures and algorithms.
- Knows 2 languages - in one his fairly proficient.
- S/he doesn't have university education - studied CS for one year and then had to quit.
- S/he has a portfolio on GitHub with 3/4 small applications.
- S/he participates on Stack Overflow with reputation around 1500+.

S/he had 2 psychotic episodes in his/her life when s/he was convinced everyone was talking about him/her behind his/her back. The person believed that there were cameras everywhere watching him/her, and grandiose thinking that s/he is special in some way and has some special mission from God. The person had to be hospitalized and their symptoms receded after 1 month of care. Now s/he is on daily medication and acts/thinks like the average person.

Could such a person be hired? What questions should s/he be prepared for?

Comment: If the condition is now being properly treated and medicated, why should it be brought up at all?

Comment: (Oh, and this will almost certainly be closed as either primarily opinion based or workplace specific)

Comment: I would ask this person why they use him/her.   Would it change the question in any way to just pick one?

Comment: Some folks do use alternative pronouns because they don't feel either of the standard ones adequately describes their identity. However in this case I'm guessing it's just a desire for anonymity in this question.

Comment: You wouldn't put that you were diabetic or had any other "under control with treatment" condition on your resume, why would this be there? I might well hire this person -- why not? But there's no reason to go around putting diagnoses on your resume, especially those that don't require any accommodation or special consideration

Comment: @JoeStrazzere A person has to start somewhere. If everyone starts asking for job experience, the candidate will never *gain* job experience.

Comment: Degree generally acts  as a replacement  for initial experience. S/he may want to seriously consider going back to school.

Comment: The fact that s/he "couldn't" finish school would be a red flag for me, regardless of the root cause.

Comment: @cst1992 As a hiring manager, I wouldn't hire someone who has never worked before.  If they asked me for mentoring I would suggest that they either volunteer or find an entry level position someplace to gain that vital work experience.

Comment: People with diffrent mental stste might have diffrent ideas and might be beneifitial for business. That's at least what i think about hiring people who're not average john

Comment: Changed question to make it answerable rather than poll, proposing it for reopening.

Comment: In answer to the specific question "Should an applicant admit..." I don't think they should at all unless for whatever reason they feel it would give them an *advantage*. There are plenty of things that people don't admit to in interviews based on the possible prejudices of the interviewers (which there are many, whether they admit to it or not). I don't see why this should be any different. (Unless they're legally obliged to in their jurisdiction)

Answer (score 12):

Keep in mind, in many countries, specifically refusing to hire based on mental illness might be considered discrimination based on disability, and possibly illegal.  If (s)he has marketable skills as a developer, and the disability is managed, so that (s)he does not require unreasonable accommodations, then yes, (s)he should be hirable, even if the reality is there is a huge stigma on mental illnesses. (S)he should avoid disclosing during the hiring process to minimize discrimination, which I think is perfectly reasonable, because it sounds like (s)he doesn't need any accommodation that would be a particular hardship on the employer, as long as his/her condition remains stable as it is now, and (s)he has a reasonable expectation the (s)he will remain stable.

Answer (score 5):

I would hire hir for a job that fits hir skills; under control is under control, and many of us have chronic conditions that could be problems if they flare up.

However, without either degree or prior experience I would be skeptical about those skills and would certainly hesitate to offer a technical position beyond the most limited  until capability had been proved. Effectively, a degree is a recommendation.

Going back for a degree would fix this. Or applying for a marginally technical job and working hir way up from there by demonstrating competence in progressively more challenging tasks... If those entry jobs exist.

Comment: (For those who haven't encountered it, "hir" is one of the many attempts to create gender-neutral pronouns. I'm not wild about it myself, but it's a lot easier to say than he/she. Some folks do prefer it; all I ask is that they not fault me if I forget to use it.)

Answer (score 1):

> Would you hire a developer with paranoid schizophrenia?

Short answer is 'No I wouldn't'

Not for a position which is easy to fill. I'm not a psychiatrist, I don't know any, and I have no real idea whats involved but I wouldn't take the risk, because if the person needed some attention I wouldn't know what to do.

The only way I would take such a person is if they were sponsored in some way so there is a clear advantage for me.

Answer (score 1):

The first question to answer: Would you hire that person if he or she didn't have paranoid schizophrenia? The second question: Does your company as a whole either want to help disadvantaged people, or does your company have an advantage from hiring them? (In some countries, there might be some requirement to hire a certain number of disabled people, and this one might count as disabled without requiring you to make any physical changes to your offices). I am asking about "company as a whole" because that wouldn't be your decision, but your company's.

But you really need to get some expert advice what this particular illness means in practice. I had a colleague with some serious mental problem who I would recommend with good conscience to anyone looking for a good software developer working in company of grown-ups. There will be others who I wouldn't want anywhere near my workplace. That's something you have to find out. Plus what legal obligations or problems you might have along the road.

Answer (score 0):

I'm impressed with her credentials. I would hire her if I were in your position. But then you should consider having a good rapport with her physicians, or at least your HR department would have good rapport with her physicians.

I would recommend using Care Circles (an Android app) or a Slack channel dedicated to monitoring her condition. You should include in that channel/group: the prospective developer, her caretaker/trusted family members, you/HR department, her teammates. *But first* ask her doctors about her. They might have an insight on how you would address her needs while benefiting from her skills... assuming you're hiring her.